# NSOutlineView and Object Persistence Odd Behavior

Tags: cocoa, nsoutlineview

I'm having a hard time with this.  I am getting a very odd behavior when it comes to object persistence of a view based NSOutlineView.  Currently I have an object that contains an array of object1 that contains an array of object2 that contains an array of object3, etc...  Each each class (object) has an isEqual: method and an isEqualToObject: method.  I have revised these over and over again, they work fine.

Now when I expand an item, it is saved to the defaults plist and I have checked it, the number of items saved is correct.

What happens though is that when I open my document again; sometimes all the rows are expanded exactly as I left them, sometimes none of the rows are expanded and sometimes NSOutlineView will expand some rows but not others.

To note I am not using NSTreeController.  I am using NSOutlineView DataSource and Delegate.  The following methods are implemented like this.  Also the AutoSave name for the outline view is set.

```
- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView persistentObjectForItem:(id)item {
        return [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:item];
    }

- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView itemForPersistentObject:(id)object {
        return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:object];

}
```

Basically sometimes it works, sometimes it half works and sometimes not at all.  It is very random.

The odd thing is that I've placed NSLog and each item is finding a match but... the outline view is not expanding it.

Comment: i think you should use `[item representedObject]` to get the underlying object aka as in your model.

Comment: additionally, when checking my code i found that I call in `awakeFromNib`of my document class `[self.groupView setAutosaveExpandedItems:YES];`. I remember reading that you have to call it manually. I assume you also have set the autosave name?

Comment: I already have the autosave name set.  [item representedObject] only works if I'm using NSTreeController which I am not using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work.  So what I ended up doing is searching through each array I have for the object and return the matching object (not the persistentObject but the object that is part of my data already).  In other words

```
- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView itemForPersistentObject:(id)object {

    id persistentObject =[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:object];

    for (Class * a in dataArray) {
        if ([a isEqual:persistentObject]) {
            return a;  //instead of returning persistentObject
        }
    }
}
```

This did the trick.  I've searched long and wide for this and I hope someone finds it useful.

Comment: Could you explain your setup a little more? I'm having trouble with this, and it sounds as though your model is similar to mine, but I'm not sure. Basically, I have an array of "group" objects (aka the items that use the `HeaderCell` identifier for their views). In each group, I have items which can be nested or not. Basically, this:

Comment: `groups = @[itemArray, itemArray, itemArray];` In those item arrays, there are "items," and some have children; some don't. I'm just a bit confused by your `for` loop. What exactly are you saving? P.S. All of my data model objects are NSCoding-compliant.

Comment: @BenStock I'm not saving anything.  I'm returning the object in my array. Your example should look like

`- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView persistentObjectForItem:(id)item {
    return [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:item];
}


- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView itemForPersistentObject:(id)object {
id item  = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:object];
    for (NSArray * array in groups) {
        for (id testItem in array) {
             if ([item isEqual:testItem]) {
                return testItem;
             }
        }
    }
}
`

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying. Why is it that one can't just return the unarchived object? I read somewhere else that in custom model objects, one must implement the `-isEqual:` method, and from what you've written, that seems to be the case. P.S. Sorry for asking what you're saving. I meant to ask: what exactly are you archiving/unarchiving? The entire object, an identifier, an index set, etc., but I can see now that it's the item. Cool. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Because computers think in terms of memory.  The objects you already have allocated occupy a different memory space than the object you unarchive.  So you have to implement isEqual in each one of your objects and match.  Another method is to create a UUID for each object, archive that, then unarchive it, search your objects for the matching UUID and return the object.  You are on the right track.

Comment: It's crazy that you say that because I ended up implementing UUIDs! My thought was that archiving a string (vs an entire object), would be easier for everyone. Nice! Thanks for the help though. Sometimes, the lack of documentation in regard to some delegate/data source methods, can make me want to slam my head against the wall.